# Create Table column date format dd-mm-yyyy SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there are 3 columns to store different dates for different purposes. I would like to store the date in `dd-mm-yyyy`. Below is the code:

```
    create table PoojaDetails
(
    PoojaDetailsID int identity constraint pk_PoojaDetailsID  Primary Key, 
    ReceiptNo AS 'PB' + '/' + cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + '/' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(PoojaDetailsID AS VARCHAR(10)), 9) ,
    ReceiptDate date not null constraint df_ReceiptDate default convert(date,getdate()),
    FirstName varchar(100) not null,
    LastName varchar(100) not null,
    TelNo bigint,
    Star char(50) not null,
    Rasi char(50) not null,
    Gothram char(100) not null,
    PoojaDietyMasterID int not null,
    Schedule char(1) not null constraint df_schedule default 'F',
    PoojaDate date not null constraint df_pdate default convert(date, '29122013'),
    PayMode bit not null,
    isDonate bit not null constraint df_isDonate default 1,
    DonateAmount float(10),
    ChequeNo int,
    BankName varchar(255),
    ChequeDated date,
    UserID int,
    SupID int,
    ChangeDate date,
    Remarks varchar(255),
    isPrint char(1) constraint df_isPrint default 'N',
    isDeleted bit not null constraint df_isDeleted default 1
)
```

I would like to have the format for:
ReceiptDate
PoojaDate
ChequeDate
ChangeDate

Thanks :)

Comment: please read this article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/abhijit_desai/2010/09/07/noramlization/ and then go back and read it again. You will thank me for it in 6 months time

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet will be to store the date (if you are using SQL 2008, you should use the `DATE` datatype) in the universal format of `yyyymmdd` in the database and then use

```
CONVERT(Date,YourColumn,105)
```

when reading the data, to get it in the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReceiptDate, 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PoojaDate, 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ChequeDate , 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]
```

use this [link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for referrence....